# Resizing image before upload in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I want to resize the resolution of an image before uploading it to local storage. Right now it saves the image in its full resolution and I have to manually resize it using `width="200" height="200"` or a css tag  in aspx. I want to reduce the file size of an image before storing it, hence by resizing the image resolution when the user uploads it via button. I've tried using System.Drawing before and setting the int imageHeight and int maxWidth to be resized but couldn't seem to get it to work.

Anyone know how to do it this?

My code so far is:

```
Protected Sub btn_SavePic_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_SavePic.Click
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim SqlString As String
    If fup_Picture.HasFile Then
        Dim myGUID = Guid.NewGuid()
        newFileName = myGUID.ToString() & ".jpg"
        Dim fileLocationOnServerHardDisk = Request.MapPath("Picture") & "/" & newFileName
        fup_Picture.SaveAs(fileLocationOnServerHardDisk)
    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to save the file to disk first, you can resize it in memory. I use code similar to the following to resize an image uploaded to a photo album. The HttpPostedFile object has an InputStream property that will let you get at the actual stream. The toStream lets you stream the output to anything you want (Response, file, etc). It will ensure the picture is scaled properly to fit into a box up to 640 wide or 480 high. You may want to put those in a config file rather than hard-code them.

```
private void ResizeImage( Stream fromStream, Stream toStream )
{
    const double maxWidth = 640;
    const double maxHeight = 480;

    using( Image image = Image.FromStream( fromStream ) )
    {
        double widthScale = 1;

        if( image.Width > maxWidth )
        {
            widthScale = maxWidth / image.Width;
        }

        double heightScale = 1;

        if( image.Height > maxHeight )
        {
            heightScale = maxHeight / image.Height;
        }

        if( widthScale < 1 || heightScale < 1 )
        {
            double scaleFactor = widthScale < heightScale ? widthScale : heightScale;

            int newWidth = (int)(image.Width * scaleFactor);
            int newHeight = (int)(image.Height * scaleFactor);
            using( Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap( newWidth, newHeight ) )
            {
                using( Graphics thumbnailGraph = Graphics.FromImage( thumbnailBitmap ) )
                {
                    thumbnailGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    thumbnailGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    thumbnailGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                    Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight );
                    thumbnailGraph.DrawImage( image, imageRectangle );

                    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                        .FirstOrDefault( c => c.FormatDescription == "JPEG" );
                    if( jpegCodec != null )
                    {
                        EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters( 1 );
                        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter( Encoder.Quality, 100L );

                        thumbnailBitmap.Save( toStream, jpegCodec, encoderParameters );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thumbnailBitmap.Save( toStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            image.Save( toStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg );
        }
    }
}
```